# Python 3 check if function is executing inside multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

Is it possible to check in f if it's inside a Pool? Alternatively what is a good catch that only catches that specific error?

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]

def g(x):
    return x

def f(x):
    try:
        with Pool(2) as p:
            print(p.map(g, x))
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e))
    return x

with Pool(2) as p:
    print(p.map(f, a))
```

Comment: What specific error? And why are you creating two pools?

Comment: I'm guessing you're creating a package that uses `Pool` and you want to know whether someone is using your package in their own multiprocessing pool?

Comment: @roganjosh yes thats correct, I want to accelerate stuff if its not already running in parallel. The specific error is AssertionError

Comment: mmm, I can't do a like-for-like on this because I only have access to Windows at the moment. What exactly is throwing the `AssertionError`? From the surface of it it looks like you could either `except AssertionError:` and throw a custom exception or just let it bubble up naturally.

Comment: `__name__` is `'__mp_main__'` for subprocesses, so you could do `if __name__ == '__mp_main__'` in f(). If true, f() is running in a subprocess. Can't tell reliably if that subprocess is spawned and controlled by a pool, though

Comment: I think i found a solution:
from multiprocessing import current_process
print(current_process()._config)

Answer (score 2):

Based on johndue's answer, but cleaner:

```py
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.current_process().daemon  # True if already a subprocess
```

To avoid potential code duplication, I recommend to use a [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) as a drop-in replacement with the same interface:

```py
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.pool

if multiprocessing.current_process().daemon:
    pool_cls = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool
else:
    pool_cls = multiprocessing.pool.Pool

with pool_cls() as pool:
    pool.map()
```

If you want to apply Thread/Process specific parameters, e.g., number of workers, have a look at [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
from multiprocessing import current_process
if "daemon" in current_process()._config:
or
if "ForkPoolWorker" in str(current_process()):
```